# SVG Egg Morph Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, transformation

I'd like to morph one simple SVG Path into another one.  I'd like to use JavaScript to control when this happens.

Here's a link to a JSFiddle I created as a simplified example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmitch/RqRjq/

Here's the base code the example uses:

```
function makeEgg() {
    var svgContainer = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
    svgContainer.setAttribute("version", "1.1");
    svgContainer.setAttribute("width", "142.308px");
    svgContainer.setAttribute("height", "142.308px");
    svgContainer.setAttribute("id", "curvecontainer");
    svgContainer.setAttribute("x", "0px");
    svgContainer.setAttribute("y", "0px");
    var eggPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
    eggPath.setAttribute("id", "eggpath");
    eggPath.setAttribute("d", "M126.308,83.154c0,39.297-32.718,56.154-55.154,56.154S16,122.451,16,83.154S50,0,71.154,0S126.308,43.856,126.308,83.154z");
    eggPath.setAttribute("fill", "GoldenRod");
    svgContainer.appendChild(eggPath);
    document.getElementById('svgcontainer').appendChild(svgContainer);
}

function changeToArrow() {
    var animateEggPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'animate');
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("id", "egganimation");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#eggpath");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("attributeType", "XML");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("attributeName", "d");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("from", "M126.308,83.154c0,39.297-32.718,56.154-55.154,56.154S16,122.451,16,83.154S50,0,71.154,0S126.308,43.856,126.308,83.154z");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("to", "M126.308,95.154c0,39.297-17.333-28.667-39.769-28.667S16,134.451,16,95.154S50,12,71.154,12   S126.308,55.856,126.308,95.154z");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("dur", "4s");
    animateEggPath.setAttribute("fill", "freeze");
}

function resetToEgg() {
    var animations = document.getElementById('egganimation');
    document.getElementById('eggpath').removeChild(animations);
}
```

Using SVG, it makes an egg, morphs it into an arrow, and then resets it by removing the animate node.  The problem I'm having is the animation only works the first time.  When I try to reset it and run it again it doesn't animate any more.  It just transforms immediately into the arrow. I have to reload/refresh the browser window in order to get to do the animation again.

I know the Raphael JavaScript library is awesome for this sort of animation but all I want to do is a simple morph. My visitors will mostly be using mobile devices, so I'd like to avoid loading a library just to do this one simple animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animations run on a timeline. The animation time basically starts at 0 and then when you run the animation it runs to 4 seconds. When you remove and re-add the animation you don't reset the timeline so the animation runs from at 4 seconds which is the end point. You can restart the timeline though by calling setCurrentTime like so...

```
function resetToEgg() {
    var animations = document.getElementById('egganimation');
    document.getElementById('eggpath').removeChild(animations);
    curvecontainer.setCurrentTime(0);
    document.getElementById('arrowbutton').style.display = "inline";
    document.getElementById('resetbutton').style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first of all the code is a bit messy so I didn't spend a whole lot of time going over each line and I appologize If I missed something important.

Because your initial function `makeEgg()` to `changeToArrow()` I left those alone.

I modified the first two lines from `resetToEgg()` from:

```
var animations = document.getElementById('egganimation');
document.getElementById('eggpath').removeChild(animations);
```

To

```
var animations = document.getElementById('curvecontainer');
document.getElementById('svgcontainer').removeChild(animations);
```

So that it removes the svg element. Next I added the `makeEgg();` so that the egg is reset

Here is the fully functional version http://jsfiddle.net/berodam/hArrb/

Comment: That seems to work. I wonder why removing that animate node doesn't work? Thanks Tetraodon for the quick response. Sorry about the messy code.

Comment: Removing the entire container has the side effect of resetting the animation timeline.